# NeoComplCache makes me an extra return key press to open a new line

Tags: vim, macvim, neocomplcache

The problem is that when I am at the end of the line, and the NeoComplCache prompt up some words. I want to open a new line below by pressing the return key, but I need to press the return key 2 times.

The first time of pressing the return key dismisses the prompt up, and the second time does the supposed job, opening a new line below.

**End of the line with prompt up**
[image: End of the line with prompt up]

**Press the return key 1 time**
[image: 1 time]

**Press the return key 2 times**
[image: 2 times]

I think one of the solution is to disable the auto prompt up. But are there any solutions to solve this annoying problem?

Comment: Have no idea how to answer the question, but I would like to know the settings you use for the statusline... Can you give some info about it please?

Comment: @skeept it's a awesome plugin called powerline. And you should do the setting `laststatus=2` if you want to always show the status line. By default, vim does not show the status line when there is only 1 window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting this in your .vimrc will cause one enter keystroke to close the popup and enter a newline:

```
" <CR>: close popup and open a new line.
inoremap <silent> <CR> <C-r>=<SID>my_cr_function()<CR>
function! s:my_cr_function()
  return neocomplcache#smart_close_popup() . "\<CR>"
endfunction
```

Or try one of the other snippets in this issue:
https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplcache.vim/issues/88